# Is my SSL certificate valid?

Tags: browser, ssl, https, certificate

I have a weired behaviour with this website: https://cartefidelite.mobi/. I can not determine if the certificate is valid.

On iPhone, it said it's valid, on Androïd it said it's not! On a desktop computer it's the same, it's valid for Safari but not for Google Chrome (on Mac) - On firefox Mac it's not valid either.

So my question is: Is this certificate valid and some browser just can't succesfully build the certificate tree hierarchy to a root certificate? Or is this certificate not valid?

Here is a screenshot on **Google Chrome (13.0)** and **Safari (5.1)**:

[image]

Comment: FWIW it's valid on Opera windows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The certificate is valid but some browser just can't succesfully build the certificate tree hierarchy to the root certificate. The "globalsign domain validation CA - G2" certificate is not in the truststore of all browsers yet.

What server are you running this application on? The solution is to add the certificates from the certificate chain to your server configuration. The server will then send them to the client and everything will be fine.

On Apache HTTPD server you add the following to the configuration:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile <globalsign domain validation CA - G2.crt>
```

Comment: Ok thank you! So each browser have it's own behaviour to build the certificate tree hierarchy. The weird thing with Chrome is it says valid on the URL bar and not valid in the info panel ^^. Thanks again for the Apache config!

Comment: @Ludovic: It's not that they have different behaviour to build the certificate tree hierarchy. All browsers have a truststore wich holds all certificates that a browser trusts. If new CA certificates come available, it takes a while before such a certificate is in the truststore of all browsers. And they will have different policies on what certificates they include in their default trustore. In IE for example, go to internet options, select the Content tab and press Certificates. Now select the Trusted Root Certification Authorities tab and you see the root certificates that IE trusts.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for the GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - G2 (Expiry 13th April 2022), here it is:

[Domain Validation Root Bundle 2011](https://www.globalsign.com/support/intermediate/domain_bundle2011.php) from GlobalSign